# Socket en java: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: java, socket

espero me puedan ayudar, estoy un poco o muuy confundida con Sockets en java, el ejercicio es el siguiente...

Crear una aplicación cliente servidor donde el servidor “piensa un número” en un intervalo
conocido y el cliente intenta adivinarlo. El cliente envía al servidor el numero posible y para ayudar
al cliente, el servidor podrá responderle al cliente cualquiera de las siguientes respuestas:

 Adivinaste

 Intenta arriba

 Intenta abajo

El cliente deberá adivinar en un número mínimo de intentos. Al finalizar el servidor le enviará el número de intentos.

En mi caso puse que fueran 5 intentos...

El código del Servidor es esté...

```
package socket3;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

/**
 *
 * @author Palomita
 */
public class Socket3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
        try{
            ServerSocket servidor=new ServerSocket(4500);
            Socket cliente=servidor.accept();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Un cliente se conectó");


            DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream resp=new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            //resp.writeObject("Hora y fecha: "+hourdateFormat.format(date));

            BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String menin=("");
            String menout=("");
            Random genera= new Random();
            int aleatorio = 1+genera.nextInt(10);

            for(int j=1;j<=5;j++){
                while(j<=5){
                    resp.writeObject("ADIVINA EL NUMERO DEL 1 AL 10 EN 5 INTENTOS");
                    menin=in.readUTF();
                    int num=Integer.parseInt(menin);
                    for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
                        if(aleatorio==num){
                        System.out.println("Adivinaste en "+i+" intentos.");
                        cliente.close();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(aleatorio>num){
                        System.out.println("Intenta Arriba, te quedan "+i+" intentos.");
                    }
                    else if(aleatorio<num){
                        System.out.println("Intenta Abajo, te quedan "+i+" intentos");
                    }
                }
                cliente.close();
                break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Y el código del Cliente es este...

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Palomita
 */
public class Cliente {
    public static void main(String[] argumentos) {
        try{
            Socket cliente=new Socket("localhost",4500);
            DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out=new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

            BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String menin=("");
            String menout=("");

            for(int j=1;j<=5;j++){
                while(j<=5){
                    ObjectInputStream entrada=new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
                    String mensaje2=(String) entrada.readObject();
                    System.out.println(mensaje2);
                    menout=b.readLine();
                    out.writeUTF(menout);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Al final me marca este error en el código del Servidor...

```
Un cliente se conectó

Intenta Abajo, te quedan 1 intentos

Intenta Abajo, te quedan 2 intentos

Intenta Abajo, te quedan 3 intentos

Intenta Abajo, te quedan 4 intentos

java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1286)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1231)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1427)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1577)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:351)
    at socket3.Socket3.main(Socket3.java:39)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)
```

Y este error en el código del Cliente...

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2681)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3156)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
    at Cliente.main(Cliente.java:23)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Espero me puedan ayudar :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Surge un problema cuando se cierra el `socket` del cliente en la
   clase `Socket3` dentro de los bucles (*2 de los cuales resultan
   potencialmente redundantes*), dicho `socket` debe cerrarse fuera de
   la iteración del primer `for`.

Ahora, tomando y comentando el código
    que proporcionas:

***Clase Socket3:***

```
try {
  //...
  //...

  for(int j=1;j<=5;j++){
    //while(j<=5){
      resp.writeObject("ADIVINA EL NUMERO DEL 1 AL 10 EN 5 INTENTOS");
      menin=in.readUTF();
      int num=Integer.parseInt(menin);
      //for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
          if(aleatorio==num){
            System.out.println("Adivinaste en "+j+" intentos.");
            //cliente.close();
            break;
          } else if(aleatorio>num){
            System.out.println("Intenta Arriba, te quedan "+(5-j)+" intentos.");
          } else if(aleatorio<num){
            System.out.println("Intenta Abajo, te quedan "+(5-j)+" intentos");
          }
      //} fin for
      //cliente.close();
      //break;
    //} fin while
  }
  cliente.close();
} catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2. Surge un problema cuando se intenta, por cada iteración, crear un nuevo objeto `ObjectInputStream`, solo es necesario uno, así que `entrada` debe estar instanciado **fuera** del ciclo `for`.

De igual manera, tomando el código y modificando:

***Clase Cliente:***

```
//...

ObjectInputStream entrada=new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
for(int j=1;j<=5;j++){
  //while(j<=5){
    //ObjectInputStream entrada=new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
    String mensaje2=(String) entrada.readObject();
    System.out.println(mensaje2);
    menout=b.readLine();
    out.writeUTF(menout);
  //}
}

  //...
```

Después de la anterior depuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! Disculpa por tanto ciclo jeje, estoy aprendiendo apenas Java y estoy en este tema, me parece que no e entendido bien la parte de InputStream y OutputStream. MIL GRACIAS en verdad <3